# Making an inline element wrap twice as much as its sibling

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a layout where inline label elements wrap twice per line of a sibling text element. The goal is for the labels to align with the text's height, wrapping twice in a line to match the text's height, and then continuing on the next line in a similar fashion. The labels should always be half the height of the text to facilitate this double wrapping.

This is the desired effect:

[image: desired effect: labels wrapping twice inside height on text element]

Challenges:

- The label lengths vary.
- The text's height changes with screen size.

What I've Tried:

- Set the line height of the labels to half that of the text.
- Adjusted the height of the labels to be half of the text.

Despite these efforts, I'm not achieving the desired wrapping effect. Any advice or insights into how I can accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

```css
.custom-element {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background-color: black;
}

h1 {
  display: inline;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 5cqw;
}

.custom-element p {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>FOR EVERY ONE LINE OF TEXT</h1>
<div class="custom-element">
  <p>There should be</p>
</div>
<div class="custom-element">
  <p>two lines</p>
</div>
<div class="custom-element">
  <p>of these elements</p>
</div>
<div class="custom-element">
  <p>half the height of the sibling text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see how `The text's height changes with screen size` in your code.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rNRydzR?editors=1100

Comment: Thank you both Paulie_D and Kosh - I've updated the example to make the text variable height. Is there a way to make the labels adapt to this height too?